# Strange display of p:fileUpload component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use the fileUpload component of PrimeFaces and everything is working **BUT** an empty error message is displayed when the component appeared with no content and i do not understand why.

[image]

And if i add a file to the component is disappeared well but it is still not pretty to have it when the component loads.

```
// View
<h:form>
  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}" />
</h:form>

// ManagedBean
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    System.out.println("handleFileUpload : " + file);
}
```

The managed bean function is well called when I click on the upload button.

Hope some could understand my problem !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are just using this form? Nothing more? And what is your PF version and JSF impl/version?

Comment: @Kukeltje My form has several other inputs which are working fine and is in a p:dialog component, but yes, nothing more. I recently upgraded PF from 6.0 to 6.1 but it was not working on 6.0, and i am sorry but i do not know what i can answer about the JSF impl/version, sorrry.